# How to disable link using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Is there a way to disable a image link using bootstrap? Below is my jade code and I tried adding the 'disabled' class and it did not work...

Any ideas?

```
a(href='/home/action2') 
  i.fa.fa-share-alt.fa-lg.img.disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
a.btn.btn-lg.disabled(href='/home/action2')
    i.fa.fa-share-alt.fa-lg
```

Comment: This does NOT work for me since you are adding the btn class which makes it a button.

Comment: Bootstrap does not disable images, it disables buttons and links. Since you're using FontAwesome, you don't have to use the .btn class. In other words, you should add the .disabled class to your outer anchor, not the inner content (whether it is an image or text)

Answer (score 0):

```
a(href='/home/action2' id="myAnchor") 
  i.fa.fa-share-alt.fa-lg.img.disabled
```

How about using javascript to change the link to #
and vice versa when you need it.

```
a(href='/home/action2' id="myAnchor") 
  i.fa.fa-share-alt.fa-lg.img.disabled
```

script

```
document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "#";
document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "/home/action2";
```